# Boundary term Ricci tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, field-theory, curvature, boundary-terms

Let
$$X = -\frac{1}{2} \nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla_\mu \varphi$$
with $\varphi$ a scalar field. I am trying to show that
$$XR = G_{\mu \nu} \nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla^\nu \varphi$$
up to boundary terms.

My attempt was to write:

\begin{equation}
G_{\mu \nu} \nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla^\nu \varphi = (R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} R)\nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla^\nu \varphi = R_{\mu \nu}\nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla^\nu \varphi - \frac{1}{2}R\nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla_\mu \varphi. \\
\end{equation}

Clearly we need that $R_{\mu \nu}\nabla^\mu \varphi \nabla^\nu \varphi$ is a boundary term. But why is this a boundary term?

Comment: I do not know the answer, but it may be helpful to create total derivatives using the nablas and use the Bianchi identity.

Comment: Does $\varphi$ obey some equation of motion? What is the context?

Comment: @Javier, No it is completely general. I have found the issue already. I did not take into account that $\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu \nabla_\nu \varphi \neq \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu \varphi$. This precisely gives a term which cancels the Ricci tensor term.

Comment: Try to expand Ricci tensor in $R_{ab}\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi$ as $R_{acbd}\nabla^a\phi\nabla^b\phi g^{cd}$, and then use the commutation relation of covariant derivative $v_{a;bc}-v_{a;cb}=R_{abcd}v^d$. Manipulate the obtained expression and see if you can write it as total divergence